# How to use PersistentUnorderedMap on NEAR contract using AssemblyScript? PersistentUnorderedMap does not appear in Contract Storage after init

Tags: nearprotocol

In my contract I am attempting to use `PersistentMap` and `PersistentUnorderedMap`.

In my class I'm doing the following:

```
import { PersistentMap, PersistentUnorderedMap } from "near-sdk-core";

public vehicleOwners: PersistentMap<AccountId, VehicleOwner>;
public vehicleOwnersPmap: PersistentUnorderedMap<AccountId, VehicleOwner>;

constructor(public vehicle:string = 'Mini') {
    this.vehicleOwners = new PersistentMap<AccountId, VehicleOwner>("vo"),
    this.vehicleOwnersPmap = new PersistentUnorderedMap<AccountId,VehicleOwner>("pma")
  }

// Model
@nearBindgen
class VehicleOwner {
  constructor(public vehicleOwner: AccountId, public dateAcquired: string) {}
}
```

After running the `init` method `near call $CONTRACT init --accountId $CONTRACT`

If I check the contract's storage I see vehicleOwners but I do not see vehicleOwnersPmap.

```
state: {
  "vehicle": "Mini", 
  "vehicleOwners": {                                                             
     "_elementPrefix": "vo::"                                                     
   }

}
```

Comment: I think we ended up fixing this by decorating the `VehicleOwner` class with `@nearBindgen` right?

Comment: This is a different issue. When the @nearBindgen decorator was missing on a class that had an Array as a member of that class, trying to add items to the array would not be persisted in storage. In this problem I am not seeing those instance variables of  `PersistentUnorderedMap` after init.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out that after running one transaction and then seeing storage I can now see in state the `PersistentUnorderedMap` instance variable being set to null. I am still not sure why it won't show after init. This is different from `PersistentMap` where you can see it on state after init.

```
state: {
  "vehicle": "Mini",
  "vehicleOwnersPmap": null, 
  "vehicleOwners": {                                                             
     "_elementPrefix": "vo::"                                                     
   }
}
```